# Google Apps Scriptでbase64の画像を保存したい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, base64

gasで下記のコードで画像をbase64でエンコードしたものをデコードしblobで保存したいと思っています。

しかし7行目の`Utilities.base64Decode(data);`で「文字列をデコードできませんでした。」というエラーが出てしまいます。

他のbase64も試しましたが結果は変わりませんでした。

下記コードのbase64は[Wikipedia - Data URI scheme](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)から
他には[Base64エンコーダー](https://lab.syncer.jp/Tool/Base64-encode/)のようなサービスでエンコードしたものを使用しました。

解決策や代替案があればよろしくお願いします。

```
function writeFile() {  
  var drive = DriveApp.getFolderById('<< folder id >>');
  var fileName = 'sample.png';
  var contentType = 'image/png';
  var data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';  

  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(data);

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(decoded, contentType, fileName)

  drive.createFile(blob);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

変数 dataに代入しているBase64でエンコードされた文字列が間違っています。

最初の"data:image/png;base64,"を除いた文字列をbase64Decodeの引数にすればOKだと思います。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます